# How to add precompiled chapters in a book?

Tags: chapters, books

I’m writing a book. I have created separate files for all chapters and have compiled them individually. I did so because when I keep all the chapters in a single file, it takes lot of time to compile. So after perfecting each chapter, I make a file that has the code of all the chapters and then I compile to get the book. This seems inefficient. Is there a way to load all the precompiled chapters in a single file and generate the pdf quickly? Or is there any other more efficient method I can use?

Comment: If you don't need cross-references between the chapters, you can use `pdfpages` to combine the single PDFs. However, I do not see, that one final compilation (with three, four or maybe five LaTeX runs) with all the chapters is a real problem for a book.

Comment: the easiest way to get a coherent combination with combined table of contents, index, etc is to comment out the preamble of each chapter and `\include` them in to your main document

Comment: For the situation described, try the `subfiles` package. Works for me. You would change the document class of the individual component files, then incorporate them into a single master document. The component files read the master preamble and document class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to get a coherent combination with combined table of contents, index, etc is to comment out the preamble of each chapter and `\include` them in to your main document.

When working on a specific chapter you can use `\includeonly{chapter-name}` in the preamble and latex will just process that chapter. As long as the `.aux` files from a full run are available all references and counters from non-included chapters will still work.